# Gulp divide stream, use two destinations (streams)

Tags: stream, gulp

I have a stream in gulp, but I want to split the stream into two, and put half in one destination, and the other half in another.

My thoughts is that I need to fork the stream twice, filter each of the new streams, use `gulp.dest` on each stream, then merge them back, and return them back to gulp.

I currently have the code,

```
function dumpCpuProfiles(profileDirectory) {
  const _ = require('highland');
  const stream = _();

  const cpuProfiles = stream
    .fork()
    .pipe(filter('*.cpuprofile'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(profileDirectory));

  const noCpuProfiles = _(cpuProfiles).filter(() => false);

  const otherFiles = stream
    .fork()
    .pipe(filter(['**', '!**/*.cpuprofile']));

  return _([noCpuProfiles, otherFiles]).merge();
}
```

However, I get the error,

```
TypeError: src.pull is not a function
at /home/user/project/node_modules/highland/lib/index.js:3493:17
at Array.forEach (native)
at pullFromAllSources (/home/user/project/node_modules/highland/lib/index.js:3492:15)
at Stream._generator (/home/user/project/node_modules/highland/lib/index.js:3449:13)
at Stream._runGenerator (/home/user/project/node_modules/highland/lib/index.js:949:10)
at Stream.resume (/home/user/project/node_modules/highland/lib/index.js:811:22)
at Stream._checkBackPressure (/home/user/project/node_modules/highland/lib/index.js:713:17)
at Stream.resume (/home/user/project/node_modules/highland/lib/index.js:806:29)
at Stream.pipe (/home/user/project/node_modules/highland/lib/index.js:895:7)
at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/user/project/gulpfile.js:189:6)
```

The output *is* a stream, so I'm not too sure what the error is about. Any help would be massively useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use this little small monkeypatching trick to achieve it

```
Object.prototype.fork = function(_fn) {
  _fn(this);
  return this;
};
```

Stream is only event emitter, pipe method doesn't return old stream but a new one, so you can built fork functionality very easy.